# Replace NAs based on values surrounding them

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vector, na

Let's say I have a vector that is full of `NA`s except for every 5th value, which could either be one of two levels:

```
RNGkind('Mersenne-Twister')
set.seed(42)

x <- NULL
for(i in 1:1000){
  x <- c(x,c(sample(c('Hey', 'Hullo'), 1, rep = F), rep(NA, 4)))
}
x
```

I want to fill the `NA`s based on what is surrounding them:

```
"Hullo" NA NA NA NA "Hey": NAs become "Hey" 
"Hullo" NA NA NA NA "Hullo" NAs become "Hullo"
"Hey" NA NA NA NA "Hullo": NAs become "Hullo"
"Hey" NA NA NA NA "Hey": NAs become "Hey"
```

I've come up with a `for` loop that looks at each element iteratively and fills the `NA`s based on a lot of `if` statements:

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if(!is.na(x[i])){
     next
   }else{
    if(x[i-1] == 'Hullo' & x[i+4] == 'Hullo' | x[i-1] == 'Hey' & x[i+4] == 'Hullo'){
      x[i:(i+3)] <- 'Hullo'
    }else{
      x[i:(i+3)] <- 'Hey'
    }
  }
}
```

But it's a bit of a hacky way of doing it, nor does it deal with the tail-end of the vector, where there could be an `NA`. Ideally, the last group of `NA` would match the output from the last group.

If it makes it any easier, there will always be four `NA`s in between two non-`NA`s.

Is there:

1. a more elegant/faster way to do this?
2. a way to fill up the end of the vector without having to do it manually?

***EDIT:*** Added what the last group of `NA`s would be and to confirm that non-`NA`s would always occur at consistent intervals (every 5th element)

Comment: Hi Ronak:
1. The last value that's NA, the output for the last group would match that of the previous group.
2. Yes, there are always 4 NAs in between the two non-NAs.

Comment: Hmmm, not quite, there were some mismatches: If you ran the for loop and then yours:
x1 <- x
x[is.na(x)] <- rep(x[!is.na(x)], each = 4)
all(x == x1)
It'll return a FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `tidyr` package :

```
xres <- tidyr::fill(data = data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), x, .direction = "up")
xres <- tidyr::fill(data = xres, x, .direction = "down")
xres$x
```

First you fill in one direction, and then fill in the other direction to get last values

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your question, I try to answer using the `tidyverse` approach.

Load the libray:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Load your data:

```
var1 <- c("Hullo",NA,NA,NA,NA,"Hey")
var2 <- c("Hullo",NA,NA,NA,NA,"Hullo")
var3 <- c("Hey",NA,NA,NA,NA,"Hullo")
var4 <- c("Hey",NA,NA,NA,NA,"Hey")

my_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(var1,var2,var3,var4))
```

Then use the `fill` function:

```
my_df %>% 
    fill(... = var1:var4,.direction = "up")
```

this is the result:

```
   var1  var2  var3 var4
1 Hullo Hullo   Hey  Hey
2   Hey Hullo Hullo  Hey
3   Hey Hullo Hullo  Hey
4   Hey Hullo Hullo  Hey
5   Hey Hullo Hullo  Hey
6   Hey Hullo Hullo  Hey
```